# Redirect example.com:81 to example.com

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect `www.example.com:81/site/` to `www.example.com`. I have used mod_rewrite a few times, is it possible to solve this in a similar way?

Comment: Make sure you use a technique that returns a `301 Permanent Redirect` as I might cause browsers to update their bookmarks!

Comment: But as noted in comments (below): "`www.example.com:81/site/` doesn't exist anymore."

Answer (score 1):

On `example.com:81` create *.htaccess* file (where `site/` is):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  (.*)  http://example.com:80/$1  [P,L]
```

With this when you go to `example.com:81` the site will proxy to `example.com`.

Comment: I can't create .htaccess file on www.example.com:81/site/.
The site doesn't exist anymore. Just www.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code you can use in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:81/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a web server running at `www.example.com:81`, and create a *.htaccess* file there.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^81$   # check if port 81
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^site/ # check if it starts with "site/"
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

`[R=301,L]` if you want permanent redirect (the :81 taken out of SEO results for example).
*Im not really sure if you have to add `:80` after the `%{SERVER_NAME}`, please let me know so I can update the answer.*